# In Windows XP and 200x servers, are multilingual user interface packs sufficient for localization testing?

Tags: windows, localization, multilingual

Has anybody any experience that an application would only work with the MUI but not with the native OS or vice versa?  Or does anybody know what is the difference between the two systems that developers who develop localized applications should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

See the Best Practices section of this [Application Compatibility in Windows MUI](https://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/handson/dev/AppCompatInMUI.mspx)

In general there are few differences if your a Unicode application and you don't check the system locale and you don't hard code any common folder paths.